Extending airflow flask api errorhandler, but I got Error: Working outside of application context
This is how I am trying to extend the app:
from flask import current_app

with current_app.app_context():
    current_app.register_error_handler(AssertionError, )

what could be wrong ?

could you explain the reason? are you using a custom plugin?
